# Uploaded excel workbook to SharePoint auto updates when changes made to the original

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have uploaded an excel workbook we constantly update to SharePoint for coworkers to view remotely as it has information they need. Would I have to delete and replace the workbook every time we make a change or is there a way that the workbook in SharePoint can automatically update with changes we make to the original which is on a Y drive? Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

When using SharePoint I find that there's an option to view the files in a document library using Windows Explorer.  When you do that you can get the path out of the address bar and use that to update the file instead of the 'Y' drive.  Benefit being you could also turn on version history in SharePoint then whenever anyone uploads a new version you can go to the past versions through SharePoint.

If your users don't all have access to SharePoint you could drag and drop from the Y drive to the address from the 'View in Windows Explorer' link or even automate it by writing a DOS batch job using the COPY command to copy the file over.  Then you can use windows task scheduler to run the .BAT file however often you want.

Hope that helps!